# Primefaces hide label in p:message

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces

I use primefaces 4.0 with Apache MyFaces 2.

I use beanValidation with Primefaces p:message component which works fine.
But primefaces inserts the label (or ID if label is null) of the inputcomponent at the beginning of the faces messages like:

```
userid: Userid should not be null.
```

The message "userid should not be null" is set from beanvaildiation message.
How can I remove the label/id tag "userid:" in message?

JSF:

```
<h:outputLabel for="userid" value="User-ID"/>
<p:inputText id="userid" label="userid" value="#{bean.userid}"/>
<p:message for="userid" severity="error" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your application messages when using beanvalidation by writing your own **message-bundle**.

You can learn more about it [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/).

By default, BeanValidatior messages are displayed as follows:

```
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE_detail = {1}: {0}
```

{1}: is the name of the component

{0}: is the message from BeanValidator.

If you don't want the label of the component to be displayed simply change it to:

```
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE_detail = {0}
```

Comment: Nice this is exactly what I searched for. Thank you!

Comment: Consider customizing the BeanValidator messages by creating a file called **ValidationMessages.properties** on your application's default package.